# Remove case from code

Tags: php, case

config.php

```
define('DB_TYPE', 'MYSQL');
```

dbManager.php

```
incude_once('config.php');
switch ( DB_TYPE ) {
   case 'MYSQL':    $this->_dataObject = MySqlDB::_getInstance();   break;
   case 'PGSQL':    $this->_dataObject = PostgreDB::_getInstance(); break;
   case 'SQLITE':   $this->_dataObject = SqliteDB::_getInstance();  break;
}
```

Can this piece of code be rewritten without the case? Something like:

```
$this->_dataObject = DB_TYPE::_getInstance();
```

This gives me an error `Fatal error: Class 'DB_TYPE' not found .... in line ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe

```
$DBClassName = 'MySqlDB';
$this->_dataObject = $DBClassName::_getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$c = TYPE;
$this->_dataObject = $c::_getInstance();
```

however, this code looks like it could benefit from dependency injection

```
class YourClass {

  public function __construct(DataObject $dataObject) {
    $this->_dataObject = $dataObject;
  }

}
```

then pass the dataobject to your class while instantiating it

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbClasses = array(
    'MYSQL' => 'MySqlDB',
    'PGSQL' => 'PostgreDB',
    'SQLITE'=> 'SqliteDB',
};

$dbClass = $dbClasses[DB_TYPE];

$this->_dataObject = $dbClass::_getInstance();
```